# How to insert a quote type text in word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I often make notes and the documents becomes long and monotonous. Sometimes I want to insert a something of importance in a text block like a table where I can set background color. This to make it stand out and break the monotonous of document as well.

How can I do that easily?

This is example the kind of thing I want to achieve.

[image]

Current I do this writing my text that I want to show in table like way. The *Insert Table* > *Draw Table*. Now I draw the table around the block of text and then I right click to change background. I also like to change vertical alignment to center but that's even more clicks.

It would be nice if I at least I could create a shortcut where I select the text and apply the shortcut and it does all the customization.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Have you considered recording a macro to insert the table at the cursor, change the background colour and centre align it?

Comment: Why not just use Comments, which is available on the Review tab? There is also a function on the Review tab to use OneNote for Linked Notes.

Answer (score 0):

### I would recommend using a style formatted to include a frame.

- You can switch to the style with a keyboard shortcut.
- You can set the style so the style for following paragraph is your body text or normal style.

The easiest way to include a frame in your formatting is to create the style (new style). It should be a paragraph style. In the create style or modify style dialog, under Format you can find directions to include a frame.

- Here is my writing on [Creating Frames](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#CreatingFrames).
- Here is Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on [Marginal Text](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/MarginalText.htm) (using frames)
- Here is my article on the Microsoft site on [Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).

Answer (score 0):

Well the best way I discovered thus far is Insert -> Text Block.

It does have preformatted styles which takes the text well. They still need to be resized and re-centered but at least works better.

Wish if we can customize them (default width, centered in page etc), that would be great.